# How can i decode JSON data field that are of changeable types?

Tags: json, swift, api, decodable

I'm receiving JSON data from an API but there are some fields that sometimes are strings and other times are integers. What are the best solutions for something like that?

Here is my decode code:

```
public struct Nutriments {
    public let energy: String?
    public let energyServing: String?
    public let energy100g: String?

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        energy = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .energy)
        energy100g = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .energy100g)
        energyServing = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .energyServing)
        }
}
```

JSON example:

```
"nutriments": {
        "energy_100g": 8.97,
        "energy_serving": "55",
        "energy": "7"
}
```

And other times like this:

```
"nutriments": {
        "energy_100g": "8.97",
        "energy_serving": 55,
        "energy": 7
}
```

Comment: Ask the API developer to fix it

Comment: @CodeDifferent if i had this option dear i wouldn't have asked the question. This is an open source api and many people contribute in adding data to it and seems like the backend is not forcing a certain type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all blame the owner of the service for sending inconsistent data.

To decode both types you can check the type in the `init` method.

At least the API seems to send all keys so you can declare all struct members as non-optional

```
public struct Nutriments {

    public let energy: String
    public let energyServing: String
    public let energy100g: String

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {      
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do { energy = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .energy) }
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch { energy = String(try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .energy)) }
        do { energy100g = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .energy100g) }
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch { energy100g = String(try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .energy100g)) }
        do { energyServing = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .energyServing) }
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch { energyServing = String(try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .energyServing)) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is also not sending all fields. So i have to declare them as optionals.

Comment: I'd look for a better service .

Comment: Anyways thanks vadian your solution is working fine for me till now :)))

Comment: I saw a site transmitting dress sizes. Sizes like 10, 12, 14 were integers, 10-12 or 12-14 was a string :-(

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to declare a custom wrapper over `Double` that knows how to decode himself from either strings or doubles:

```
struct DoubleLike: Decodable {
    public let value: Double

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            value = try container.decode(Double.self)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            let valueString = try container.decode(String.self)
            if let dbl = Double(valueString) {
                value = dbl
            } else {
                throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Could not convert \(valueString) to Double"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'd be able to easily use this in your struct:

```
struct Nutriments: Decodable {
    public let energy: DoubleLike
    public let energyServing: DoubleLike
    public let energy100g: DoubleLike

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case energy
        case energyServing = "energy_serving"
        case energy100g = "energy_100g"
    }
}
```

This solution has the advantage of being scalable, the downside is that you'll always need to extract the `.value` property before being able to use the decoded double.

Another solution would involve writing your own `Decoder` implementation, however that might not worth the effort.